# Where can I find great Windows XP themes?

Tags: windows-xp, themes

For the last couple of years I have used the [Zune theme for Windows XP](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2006/11/03/windows-xp-zune-theme/). Once the background picture is removed it is a very classy look for XP.

Is there a place on the web where I can find other Windows themes are available to download and try?

Do you have any recommendations for individual themes to use?

Comment: I like the Windows 7 theme, though you have to replace your entire OS for it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## DeviantART

DeviantART is a fantastic resource for customisation. Check out their [Windows Skins and Themes](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows/) section for themes for most of the 3rd party theming apps out there.

[Visual Styles](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows/visualstyle/) are generally for Windows XP and require **no third party applications** to use them. However, you will need this [UxStyle UXTheme Patcher](http://uxstyle.com/)*, which supports Windows XP, Vista and 7 RC1.

[image]

For Windows Vista (and XP), you can use [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/). DeviantART has a [section](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows/windowblinds/#order=9) dedicated for WindowBlinds themes.

<sub>* Thanks to Grawity who pointed out that the previous patcher was incompatible with Windows XP SP3, and suggested this alternative</sub>

Comment: As far as I know, Neowin's patcher doesn't support XP SP3, so you might have to install the patched file manually from http://www.withinwindows.com/uxtheme-patches/

Answer (score 0):

When I was using XP, I really enjoyed [Human Theme for Windows](http://fioressj.deviantart.com/art/Human-for-Windows-37743373) ported from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding WindowBlinds, the Stardock products tend to  look very good, but IMHO can be resource hogs and very difficult to remove from your machine.